# Error in kmodes() for categorical datasets with missing values (or alternate algorithms) with r

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a small dataset with 11 columns and 50 rows (plus a header row). 
I'm trying to apply the `kmodes` clustering method (from `klaR` package) in R to this text matrix. Unfortunately, I get an error that I cannot comprehend:

```
kmodes(data, 5)
```

> Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero

What is the problem? 
If I change it to:

```
kmodes(na.omit(data), 5)
```

The error is:

> 'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [0]

The data looks like this

```
Type  A1   A3   B5    C1   C2    C4    D5    D     E2      E1
1  A  pos   pos  neg  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     U
2  A  pos   pos  neg  <NA> <NA>  <NA>   pos  <NA>  <NA>     U
3  A    U   pos  pos  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   pos  <NA>
4  A  pos   pos  neg  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   neg     U
5  A  pos   pos  neg  <NA> <NA>   pos  <NA>  <NA>   neg  <NA>
6  A  pos   pos <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   neg   neg   neg
```

Comment: Take a look at what `tmp <- na.omit(data)` looks like. Are there any rows left in it after removing NA values?

Comment: No there aren't. Why are the whole rows removed instead of those specific NAs?

Comment: Often people want to fit a model only to a 'complete dataset' that has no missing data. So they use a function like `na.omit` or `complete.cases` to remove any rows that contain an NA value in any column.   see: `help(topic="na.omit", package="stats")`

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the `NA` values in all the rows. Omitting the `NA` values will give you an empty data frame, something like this:

```
# [1] Type A1   A3   B5   C1   C2   C4   D5   D    E2   E1  
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

However, if you just replace all the `NA` values in your data to, let's say, an empty string `""`, it will work. Something like this:

```
kmodes(na.fill(data, fill=""), 5)
```

The `na.fill(data, fill="")` will give you this data:

```
#     Type A1    A3    B5    C1 C2 C4       D5       D        E2    E1   
#[1,] "A"  "pos" "pos" "neg" "" "" ""       ""       ""       ""    "U"  
#[2,] "A"  "pos" "pos" "neg" "" "" ""    "pos"       ""       ""    "U"  
#[3,] "A"  "U"   "pos" "pos" "" "" ""       ""       ""    "pos"     ""   
#[4,] "A"  "pos" "pos" "neg" "" "" ""       ""       ""    "neg"    "U"  
#[5,] "A"  "pos" "pos" "neg" "" "" "pos"    ""       ""    "neg"     ""   
#[6,] "A"  "pos" "pos" ""    "" "" ""       ""    "neg"    "neg"  "neg"
```

And the output of `kmodes` now will be:

```
#K-modes clustering with 5 clusters of sizes 1, 1, 2, 1, 1

#Cluster modes:
#  Type  A1  A3  B5 C1 C2  C4 D5   D  E2  E1
#1    A   U pos pos                  pos    
#2    A pos pos neg                  neg   U
#3    A pos pos neg                        U
#4    A pos pos                  neg neg neg
#5    A pos pos neg       pos        neg    

#Clustering vector:
#[1] 3 3 1 2 5 4

#Within cluster simple-matching distance by cluster:
#[1] 0 0 1 0 0

#Available components:
#[1] "cluster"    "size"       "modes"      "withindiff" "iterations" "weighted"
```

Hope it helps.